# How to write metadatas to a file?

Tags: php, symfony, metadata

I am currently developing a web solution in PHP 8.0 using Symfony 5.3.7 where I need to allow user to download a file with custom metadatas.

For example, I have on the server a file a.jpg and I created a metadata "Resume: John is looking to Marie", which is stored and linked to the file in database.

If a user click on a button to download the file, I need to set the metadata stored in database to the file before the user download it, then if he bring is a.jpg in USB key or whatever, the metadata is in it.

Does anyone knows how to do with Symfony or even native PHP?

I am thinking of create a download function to do this but I don't find how to write the metadata in the file.

The only thing I could find is this https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pharfileinfo.setmetadata.php, but I don't even understand how it works.

I need this for multiple file types : images, videos, audios and PDFs.

Comment: Do you want to add the metadata as EXIF information directly to the image?

Comment: @Roman It can be a solution for images. But actually I want a solution for more type of files than just images : videos, audios and PDFs are also in my system :/

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way to add arbitrary metadata like this to a file, regardless of whether you're using PHP or anything else.

At its most basic, a file is just a series of bits, and the way we interpret those bits is what we call a "file format". Some file formats are very simple - the whole file is interpreted as a series of letters, or a series of coloured pixels; others are much more complex, with different sections interpreted as different types of information.

A JPEG image file, for instance, can have sections of data referred to as "EXIF information", which can store details about the image, including arbitrary text. Similarly, MP3 files can have sections called "ID3", which are used to store things like track and artist names to be displayed by media players. You can probably find tools or libraries for editing both of those formats, but you won't be able to use an EXIF editor on an MP3 file or an ID3 editor on a JPEG.

The function you found was for managing the metadata on PHAR files, which are PHP code archives. It's not going to be useful for editing images, PDFs, or anything else.

So, you need to identify the different types of file you want to edit, and then find out two things: firstly, does the file format have anywhere to put the metadata *at all*; and secondly, what tools can edit the metadata *in that particular file type*. You might find some libraries or tools which can manage metadata in multiple audio formats, or multiple image formats, but chances are you're going to need to integrate more than one to get the breadth of support you seem to want.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for this very detailed solution. I understood everything. I'll search about this !